# Spring: Environment specific configuration

Tags: java, spring, properties, environment-variables

Using Spring I need some kind of environment (dev|test|prod) specific properties.

I have exactly one configuration file (myapp.properties) and for some reasons I cannot have more than one configuration file (even spring can handle more than one).

So I need the possibility to add properties with a prefix like

```
dev.db.user=foo
prod.db.user=foo
```

and tell the application which prefix (environment) to use with a VM-argument like `-Denv-target` or something like this.

Comment: Look into Profiles. You won't have to mix different properties in the same files. You would have specific properties files for each environment. [To get you started](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/).

Comment: Profiles would be a logical place to start. If that doesn't meet your needs I'd consider creating a property file locator class; for example we've created ones to load property files based on user and/or machine names.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, DaveNewton: Thanks for your idea. I will take a look on profiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use for this purpose a subcass of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`:

```
public class EnvironmentPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static final String ENVIRONMENT_NAME = "targetEnvironment";

    private String environment;

    public EnvironmentPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        super();
        String env = resolveSystemProperty(ENVIRONMENT_NAME);
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(env)) {
            environment = env;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String resolvePlaceholder(String placeholder, Properties props) {
        if (environment != null) {
            String value = props.getProperty(String.format("%s.%s", environment, placeholder));
            if (value != null) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return super.resolvePlaceholder(placeholder, props);
    }

}
```

and using it in `applicationContext.xml` (or any other spring-configuration file):

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholder"class="EnvironmentPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:my.properties" />
</bean>
```

In `my.properties` you can define properties like:

```
db.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql:///MyDB
db.username=user
db.password=secret
prod.db.username=prod-user
prod.db.password=verysecret
test.db.password=notsosecret
```

Thereby you can prefix properties keys by an environment key (e.g. `prod`).

Using the vm argument `targetEnvironment` you can choose the enviroment you like to use, e.g. `-DtargetEnvironment=prod`.

If no environment-specific-property exists, the default one (without a prefix) is choosen. (You should always define a default one.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what are your constraints to avoid having more than one configuration file but you can use something like -Denvtarget=someValue and in java do:

```
//Obtain the value set in the VM argument 
String envTarget= System.getProperty("env-target");

Properties properties;
try {
   properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("myapp.properties");
} catch (IOException exception) {
  //log here that the property file does not exist.    
}

//use here the prefix set in the VM argument.
String dbUser = properties.getProperty(envTarget+".db.user");
```

Comment: That does not work, if I need to reference the properties in the spring configuration

Comment: I understand your point, In Spring you should set: <bean id="myConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">  
        <list>  
            <value>classpath:myapp.properties</value>
        </list> 
    </property> </bean>

Answer (score 2):

If you have environment variable and want to get property according this variable you can declare your properties that way:

```
<property name="username" value="${${env-target}.database.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${${env-target}.database.password}" />
```

Also make sure that you use properly configured property-placeholder:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
```

Or, if you use special property configurer (e.g. EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer), set properties:

```
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
```

But as mentioned earlier it is better to use profiles.